# Session expired in spring MVC

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, session-timeout

How can I handle the session expired in spring MVC and what is the best place to handle it? where can I specify the session time out? It would be great if you could show me by some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sessions timeout I am using 'plain' Servlet API.

Custom `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` defined in web.xml and in method `sessionCreated` on session set timeout using `setMaxInactiveInterval` (in [s]).

I know it is 'old school', but is simple and working for me.

If you want to get timeout value from spring, there is access to ServletContext from session.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
applicationContext.getBean("...");
```

Comment: Alephx, thanks for your answer. I wanted to know where in controller classes I should check it. Should I write a separate class or method to handle it and what is the best way of checking the session?

Comment: My response was about setting own session timeout in app code. 

Not sure if you can check session state. Sessions are managed by container (Tomcat, etc) - if session expires it invalidate it. You can only check if session is valid. For this you need Filter [Servlet way] or Spring interceptor `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` [Spring MVC way]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [event mechanism in ApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events), you would then register a HttpSessionListener in web.xml that when a session timeouts fires an event in the root WebApplicationContext to all beans that observes that event. Get the root WebApplicationContext using WebApplicationContextUtils.